# Libgdx Android Studio proxy issue

Tags: android, proxy, libgdx

Recently I started learning the libgdx library and wanted to give it a try on Android Studio.

I followed up some tutorials found on different websites. The problem is when gradle sync starts, it gives an error:

> Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

I m not behind any proxy. I tried to disable firewall, enable offline / online gradle sync with the offline folder, forced the sdk to download with http instead of https, changed the `distributionUrl` into http and changed the distribution url aswell. 
Nothing worked.

I don't really know if it is a coincidence or not but when I try to launch the standalone SDK, it gives this error when trying to fetch url saved in the SDK update sites:

> Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to https://dl.google.com refused

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that:

1. Android SDK Manager > Tools > Options
2. Check "Force https://...
   sources to be fetched using http://..."